# What does “a set of things” mean?

Tags: soft-question, elementary-set-theory, definition

Suppose we defined some mathematical object $P$, where $P$ is natural number, polynomial, endofunction, geometric figure, etc. What does the expression “$A$ is a set of $P$s” mean:

- Set inclusion) For all $a\in A$, $a$ is a $P$.
- Set equality) For all $a$, $a\in A$ iff $a$ is a $P$.

If both are used, which is the most widespread one (which I can use on the Internet not explaining what I mean)?

Update 0: What does the translation to another language of the expression above mean? (Describe your native language.)

Comment: Regarding the update: If it's a good translation, it will surely mean (approximately) the same thing.  Of course, it's possible that something gets lost in translation, so that the translated phrase has a broader or a narrower meaning than the original, but even so, the fundamental _point_ of translation is to map some phrase in one language to the phrase in another language with (in a given context) the most similar meaning possible.

Comment: When I say "this is a box of cats," is there any reasonable context in which I could mean "this is the box of all cats"?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I dunno. This is still a question about mathematics, and mathematics does not normally discuss putting cats into boxes. :)

Comment: @beroal, Qiaochu: Indeed, [that's physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat), not math.  (However, this question is really more about language than math anyway, even if it does refer specifically to language as used by mathematicians.)

Answer (score 8):

I'd say "$A$ is *a* set of $P$s" for the first, and "$A$ is *the* set of (all) $P$s" for the second.

Comment: Interesting. However, there may be no “a”/“the” in another language!

Comment: @beroal: Indeed, but I'd expect any language to have _some_ way of making the distinction between "a collection of some Ps" and "the collection of all Ps".  For example, in Finnish (which has no articles like "a"/"the"), I'd translate "A is a set of Ps" as _A on joukko P:itä_ (using the partitive case), while "A is the set of Ps" would be _A on P:iden joukko_ (using the genitive case).

Comment: In (some?) other languages without such a distinction, a word meaning "all" is mandatory to represent the second idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want set inclusion, you should say A is a set of P's.

If you want set equality, you should say A is the set of all P's.

The words "a" and "the" (most often) have very specific meanings in mathematics.